# Cookie with $var in name issue php

Tags: php, cookies

This code won't work:

```
$var = "John";
if(setcookie($var,"info", time() + 3600)) {
    echo 'TRUE';
}
```

This one works:

```
if(setcookie("John","info", time() + 3600)) {
    echo 'TRUE';
}
```

I can see the "TRUE" word in both cases, but in the first one the cookie is missing every time without error.

I'm working with wordpress if it helps.

Comment: How are you calling the cookie? Like this `$_COOKIE[$var]` or this `$_COOKIE["John"]`?

Comment: What output does changing `echo 'TRUE';` to `echo 'TRUE: #'; var_dump($var); echo '#';` produce?

Comment: bloodyKnuckles: firstone
x-ray: John

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "cookie_name";
$cookie_value = "Cookie Value";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30));
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

You can call both of $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] or $_COOKIE["name"] $_COOKIE is a global variable, if cookie expire time < time(), you loose the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$var = "John";
setcookie($var,"info", time() + 3600, "/");

if(isset($_COOKIE['John']))
{
  echo "True";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, my mistake. I was actually putting as cookie name a db value that was like "someting.something".

The only thing I did to make it work was to delete the dot. --> "somethingsomething".

Cookies doesn't like dots... Thank you all!